# dplyr: Integer sampling within mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to generate a column in a `tbl_df` that is a random integer of 0 or 1. This is the code I am using:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(0)

#Dummy data.frame to test
df <- tbl_df(data.frame(x = rep(1:3, each = 4)))

#Generate the random integer column
df_test = df %>% 
  mutate(pop=sample(0:1, 1, replace=TRUE))
```

But this does not seem to work the way I expected. The field I generated seems to be all zeros. Is this because the statement within `mutate` is evaluated in parallel and hence ends up using the same seed for the first random draw?

```
df_test 
Source: local data frame [12 x 2]

   x pop
1  1   0
2  1   0
3  1   0
4  1   0
5  2   0
6  2   0
7  2   0
8  2   0
9  3   0
10 3   0
11 3   0
12 3   0
```

I am breaking my head over this the past few hours. Any idea what is the flaw in my script?

Comment: Use `sample(0:1, 12, replace=TRUE)`

Comment: Or `sample(0:1, n(), replace = TRUE)`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The way your code is written, you are assigning a single value (the result of the random draw) to the entire vector (this is called "vector recycling").

The best solution in this case is Steven Beaupré's answer, creating a randomized vector the length of your data.frame:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(pop = sample(0:1, n(), replace = TRUE))
```

---

Generally, if you want to apply a function row-by-row in `dplyr` - as you thought would happen here - you can use `rowwise()`, though in this example it's not required.

Here's an example of `rowwise()`:

```
df2 <- data.frame(a = c(1,3,6), b = c(2,4,5))

df2 %>%
  mutate(m = max(a,b))

  a b m
1 1 2 6
2 3 4 6
3 6 5 6

df2 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(m = max(a,b))

  a b m
1 1 2 2
2 3 4 4
3 6 5 6
```

Since `rowwise` groups the data by each row operations are potentially slower than without any grouping. Therefore, it's mostly better to use vectorized functions whenever possible instead of operating row-by-row.

---

**Benchmarking:**

The approach with `rowwise()` is about 30x slower:

```
library(microbenchmark)
df <- tbl_df(data.frame(x = rep(1:1000, each = 4)))
bench <- microbenchmark(
  vectorized = df2 <- df %>% mutate(pop = sample(0:1, n(), replace = TRUE)),
  rowwise = df2 <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(pop = sample(0:1, 1, replace = TRUE)),
  times = 1000
  )

options(microbenchmark.unit="relative")
print(bench)
autoplot(bench)

Unit: relative
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
 vectorized  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.0000  1000
    rowwise 42.53169 42.29486 36.94876 33.70456 34.92621 71.7682  1000
```

Comment: This works well. So the expression within `mutate` is not evaluated for each row without this operator? So there is some form of numpy like broadcasting happening with `mutate`?

Comment: Exactly.  I've added an illustrative example of a more typical application of `rowwise()`.

Comment: `rowwise` isn't necessary in this case. Instead, the approach in Steven's comment to the question would be best in my opinion.

Comment: @docendodiscimus I agree and I would solve this problem with Steven's approach, too.  But I thought there was benefit in explaining how `mutate` can work that way.  I'll see if he'll post his comment as an answer that we can upvote, otherwise I'll turn this into a community wiki and incorporate his approach.

Comment: Feel free to incorporate Steven's comment into your answer (you can mention his name if you like) - it's already several days ago and he didn't post an answer until now. The point is that many functions in R are vectorized and you should make use of that rather than grouping the data by each row and essentially looping through it (where it's not necessary).

Comment: So there is a performance difference between Steven's approach and the one in this answer? Can you guys elaborate a bit in terms of speed and memory usage? Pointing me to a documentation would be fine as well. I am sure I am bound to run into similar issues when using other functions. @docendodiscimus

Comment: There is a very large performance difference between the approaches; I added benchmarking results to the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if this belongs in the posted answer, but in my case `rowwise() %>% mutate()` wasn't working because I was inadvertently using `plyr::mutate` rather than `dplyr::mutate`. (You can explicitly choose the source with `mutate <- dplyr::mutate`.)